# Getting a series of Normal Distributions from a Least Squares regression

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, regression, gaussian

I am not particularly good at math. I would like to get some breadcrumbs about how to solve the following formula using python code.

- Assume an [m,n] matrix **M** and a [1,n] vector **y**.
- Solve for the least squares using `scipy.linalg.lstsq(M, y)`.
- The output will be an [m,1] vector of coefficients **a** in the equation **Ma=y**.

As per [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148803/how-does-linear-regression-use-the-normal-distribution), any vector of solutions like **a** in a regression is basically a series of single points each taken from a normal distribution that describes the error of every point on the regression. In effect, every single digit in the solution vector **a** is the mean of a normal distribution of errors centred on zero.

I would like to *find those normal distributions* rather than the scalar value for every single point in the solution. Apologies for the poor description of the mathy bits, I was never trained in math in Uni.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint. Let me know if you want more.

`scipy.linalg.lstsq(M, y)` returns four things:

```
x : (N,) or (N, K) ndarray
  Least-squares solution.

residues : (K,) ndarray or float
  Square of the 2-norm for each column in b - a x, if M > N and ndim(A) == n
  (returns a scalar if b is 1-D). Otherwise a (0,)-shaped array is returned.

rank : int
  Effective rank of a.

s : (min(M, N),) ndarray or None
  Singular values of a. The condition number of a is s[0] / s[-1].
```

`residues` is going to be of interest to you!

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html

Answer (score 0):

you do NOT need  `find those normal distributions`, Least Squares Linear (or non-linear) Regression algorithm is fitting the line (or curve) to means you're interested in... and, as pointed by Kaposci, your residuals have to be normally distributed,